# If Both Checkboxes flag false do?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, checkbox, messagebox

I am getting frustrated with Google query's on code so I'll just ask all you experts.

I have a <500 line program that lists files from clearcase in a tree now I want to click on them and check them in/out. The checkout part I can accomplish via command line or plugin (::whew:: clearcase is not easy to program with) anyhow I have to checkboxes one for checkin one for checkout and if neither are selected  (both false) I want it to notify the user. I have the following code and it works...except that it always displays the "not selected" message since one flag is always false.

```
if (checkBox1.checked == true
{
   MessageBox.Show("this")
}
if (checkBox2.checked == true 
{
   MessageBox.Show("THAT")
}
if (checkbox1.checked == false | checkbox2.checked == false)
{
   MessageBox.show("You didn't select this or THAT")
}
```

After the first choice it always says "THAT" or "this" then "You didn't select this or THAT"

Also I have the checkboxes setup so that when you check one it unchecks the other, but both can be false.

Comment: Try nesting the last if statement?

Comment: There's no actual question here.

Comment: and your | (or) should be an & (and)

Comment: Hmm, why is this not a RadioButton?  For that matter, how come you don't know why it is an check-in or check-out?

Comment: One will always be false. Thus, if (false OR false) will always be true.

Comment: You are right Boo, I missed the question but somehow it was answered anyway ;) I didnt want to use radio buttons because the tree view is tricky and sometimes i click the wrong branch just trying to expand the tree, this saves me the hassle of having to go back and recheck in or out if i click the wrong one first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to check that they are both false, and that is done with a logical AND.  The vertical bar represents an OR condition.

```
if (checkbox1.checked == false && checkbox2.checked == false)
{
    MessageBox.show("You didn't select this or THAT")
}
```

That should do what you are looking for.

Comment: That does it TYVM! I knew it would be something simple, I wasn't sure how to properly query that in Google so thanks for saving me many frustrating minutes of searching through irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Use an if-else statement instead of just an if statement.  That way it will stop after executing the first statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (checkBox1.checked)
{
   MessageBox.Show("this")
}
else if (checkBox2.checked)
{
   MessageBox.Show("THAT")
}
else
{
   MessageBox.show("You didn't select this or THAT")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
(checkbox1.checked == false & checkbox2.checked == false)
```

The vertical line is OR while the ampersand is AND

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (checkBox1.checked == true)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("this") 
} 
else if (checkBox2.checked == true)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("THAT") 
} 
else 
{ 
    MessageBox.show("You didn't select this or THAT") 
}
```

or better:

```
if (checkBox1.checked)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("this") 
} 
else if (checkBox2.checked)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("THAT") 
} 
else 
{ 
    MessageBox.show("You didn't select this or THAT") 
}
```